# specify base/initial path for company-files completion?

Tags: company-mode

I've set up company-mode in emacs and enabled the company-files backend, and am now able to start typing in code which looks like this:

```
import Foo from '../
```

and have company provide some auto-completion options, resulting in e.g.:

```
import Foo from '../../baz/bar/Foo.js
```

.  Is it now possible to configure company-files to begin its process in some other directory (e.g. `../../baz`), so that I can write code that looks like this:

```
import Foo from 'bar/Foo.js';
```

and still get autocompletion along the way?

Ideally I'd like a way to tell company-mode "traverse up the filesystem tree from this file's location until you find a directory containing a file named 'package.json' and begin auto-completion from there", but providing an absolute filesystem path string would be okay too.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible. Note that, in addition to specifying the base path, you'll need to somehow tell `company-files` (or rather, a future, expanded version of it) that strings following `import ... from` are relative file names in JavaScript.

If you ask `company-files` to treat every string as file name, there will be too many false positives.

Together with that logic, though, you might want to try writing a new backend. `company-files` itself is not big, and you probably don't even need the "listing files from all subdirectories 1 level deep" thing.

Feel free to file a feature request, but be prepared to write some Elisp, even if only to perform JS-specific configuration.